# Doctrine Mapped Superclass not recognizing primary key

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a mapped super class defined this way:

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class BaseEntity {
/**
 * @var string $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var datetime $dateCreated
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $dateCreated;

function __construct() {
    $this->id = $this->generateId();
}
```

And a subclass that extends it. I get this exception:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

I do an echo on the getId method after I construct the object and it returns a valid string so that's not it. The interesting thing is, I do a find query before I insert something into that same table. The find query recognizes the 'id' field, the insert doesn't but both recognize the date_created field. What could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are generating id on your own you should use:

```
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
```

`IDENTITY` tells doctrine to relay on database specific identity generation.

Comment: I completely overlooked that because I didn't specify auto increment but Doctrine thought I should anyway. That fixed it.